# Every Borel linearly independent set has Borel linear hull (reference?)

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

I am looking for a reference to the following fact, which probably is known and could be proved somewhere by someone.

> **Theorem.** The linear hull of any linearly independent Borel set in a Polish topological vector space $X$ is a Borel subset of $X$.

The proof easily follows from the Lusin-Souslin Theorem stating that injective continuous images of Borel sets are Borel.

Comment: The ground field is an arbitrary Polish field? To what map do you apply the Lusin-Souslin theorem?

Comment: @YCor In fact, the proof is a bit tricky, but allows to get more: the linear hull of any linearly independent Lusin set in Lusin. A space is Lusin if it has a stronger Polish topology (which can be assumed to be zero-dimensional). Each Polish zero-dimensional space $P$ embeds into the real line and inherits the linear order from the real line. So, I apply the Lusin-Suslin Theorem to the injective map $(\mathbb R\setminus \{0\})^n\times  \{(x_i)_{i\in n}\in P^n:x_0<x_1<...<x_{n-1}\}\to L$, $((\lambda_i),(x_i))\mapsto \sum_i\lambda_ix_i$.